# Предлог "в отсутствие" и существительное "в присутствии"

Tags: предлоги, падежи

Почему так правильно

```
В отсутствие Васи я не буду говорить.
В присутствии Васи я не буду говорить.
```

А так нет

```
В отсутствии Васи я не буду говорить.
В присутствие Васи я не буду говорить.
```